# How to Cache a server-side variable and have it expire in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've searched on google but could not find anything suitable. Can anyone provide sample code of how to cache a server-side variable in MVC and have it expire after 5 minutes. I want to use it in the controller class.

Many thanks.

UPDATE: I tried MemoryCache, but it updates everytime I refresh the browser, not every 5 minutes. I display ViewBag.IsTime in the browser.

```
private bool IsTimeForCountUpdate()
    {


        var cacheKey = $"MyCacheKeyName";

        MemoryCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
        int myCache = 0;

        if (cache.Contains(cacheKey))
        {
            //myCache = (int)cache[cacheKey];
            return true;
        }
        else
        {

            myCache = 1;

            CacheItem cacheItem = new CacheItem(cacheKey, myCache);
            cache.Add(cacheItem, new CacheItemPolicy() { AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(5) });

            return false;
        }

    }

public async Task<ActionResult> Dashboard(int t = 1)
    {
        ViewBag.IsTime = IsTimeForCountUpdate() ? "YES" : "NO";
```

...

Comment: I literally created a new MVC project and added to the home controller your cache function and an IntakeDashboard view with your code.  It works as expected other than I think you have your Yes/No reversed.  On the cache insertion you will want to "update", otherwise for the next 5 minutes you don't.  On the first call of the action the cache item doesn't exist and it creates it.  On subsequent calls it does exist and returns true as you wrote the code.

Comment: Perhaps, I do not quite understand what you are expecting to occur?  Maybe a misunderstanding of what you expect to occur and what I think you wanted?

Comment: it's working now..can't explain why I thought it wasn't. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome!  Glad to have helped! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**MemoryCache**

You state that you want to cache a server side variable not the content results.  In this case you can take a look at using [MemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Example:

Let's say you want to cache some data you get frequently from the database:

```
    var cacheKey = "MyCacheKeyName";

    MemoryCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
    XYZType myCache = null;

    if (cache.Contains(cacheKey))
    {
        myCache = (XYZType)cache[cacheKey];
    }
    else
    {

        myCache = GetDataIWantToCache();

        CacheItem cacheItem = new CacheItem(cacheKey, myCache);
        cache.Add(cacheItem, new CacheItemPolicy() { AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(5) });
    }
```

**Explanation**

The `if` block checks to for the existence of your item and returns it if it does.

The `else` will create your item (replace GetDataIWantToCache with whatever) since it wasn't found and insert it into the cache for five minutes.

**OutputCache**

Use the [OutputCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs) attribute if you want to cache content results for an entire controller or individual actions.  It has settings for controlling how long and if you want to have a cache per parameter and/or some parameters by using the VaryByParam property.

Some more reading for you on [caching in .Net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/performance/caching-in-net-framework-applications)

Comment: thanks for the help. I tried the example in a controller, and the cache get reset every time I refresh the browser, not every 5 minutes. is it possible to keep it cached on browser refreshes ?

Comment: Something is wrong then but I can't assist without any details of how you implemented it.  I use MemoryCache all the time in controllers and it works as expected with the above code.....

Comment: I added my implementation in an update to original post above.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use ASP.Net built-in OutputCache.

Duration is in seconds, you can store different caches by parameter using VaryByParam.

```
    [OutputCache(Duration = 300, VaryByParam = "id")]
    public ActionResult Index(int? id)
    {
        return Content(DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }
```